# Filtering out Sitecore Items before the databind

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

I want to filter out / remove items from a list of type Sitecore.Data.Items.
This is how i fill the list.

```
List<Item> actueelItems = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/destil_nl/Home/").ToList();
```

I have a method that checks wheter an item is valid. This will return true or false.
I want to put up a new list, that i will call the filteredList with only the valid items in it.

What's the best way to achieve this?

This by the way is my validate method:

```
public static bool ValidateItem(Item item)
    {
        return ValidateItem(item, true);
    }


public static bool ValidateItem(Item item, bool checkVisualization)
{
    bool result = true;
    if (item.Versions.Count <= 0 ||
        !item.Publishing.IsValid(DateTime.Today, false) ||
        (checkVisualization && item.Visualization.GetLayout(Sitecore.Context.Device) == null))
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Currently i am using the check in the itemDataBound but then the item will still be shown, only with the wrong values. I figured i have to filter the list, and give the filtered list as datasource. I just don't know how i can easily filter this list using the ValidateItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own puzzle.
Where i have the list, i will just run a linq .where and validate my items:

```
actueelItems = actueelItems.Where(c => MenuItemHelper.ValidateItem(c, false)).ToList<Item>();
```

Might be handy for someone else in the future!

Answer (score 1):

LINQ plus extension methods or wrapper classes opens up a lot of possibilities for querying and filtering sitecore items.